# Put SQL and HTML value in echo isset($person['FS'] == "")

Tags: php, html, sql, echo, isset

i want my site to echo the html in to my site and take the SQL value that i put in it

in normal php echo it would look like this

```
echo "</br><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"inputFs\" value=\"1\" " . $person['Fs'] . "/>Syns på förstasidan"
```

but how do I do when i put it in to an isset?

```
echo isset($person['Fs'] == "")) ? "</br><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"inputFs\" value=\"1\" " . $person['Fs'] . "/>Syns på förstasidan" : "";
```

Comment: Det är inget fel på din kod vad jag kan se? =S

Comment: :) English please, annars fattar inte alla (otherwise the others cannot read)

Comment: What happens when you just `echo $person['Fs']`?

Comment: when I "echo $person['Fs']" i just get the value of "Fs" it all works fine but the issue have sadly changed a little, "$person['Fs']" always gives away a value when put in the isset even if it is empty of not, so now I need to get the isset == this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Can't figure it out why you are using $person["Fs"] inside input tag
May be this should help

```
echo (isset($person['Fs']) ? '</br><input type="checkbox" name="inputFs" value="1"/>Syns på förstasidan' : '');
```

OR

If you are using $person["Fs"] for value then try this

```
echo (isset($person['Fs']) ? '</br><input type="checkbox" name="inputFs" value="' . $person["Fs"] .'"/>Syns på förstasidan' : '');
```

If your checking for a variable if it is blank or contain some particular value.
Then you don't have to use isset it works without isset
Consider your checking if $person['Fs'] == "checked" then use

```
echo ($person['Fs'] == "checked" ? '</br><input type="checkbox" name="inputFs" value="' . $person["Fs"] .'"/>Syns på förstasidan' : '');
```

Comment: That do for some reason not work beacuse $person['Fs'] do for some reason always give away a value the options of values on the Fs is nothing or "checked" so I would like something like $person['Fs'] == "checked" to work but I am not able to put in == into the php

Comment: I do not need a value in the input tag it could might as well just look like this 

"echo isset($person['Fs'] == "")) ? "</br>Syns på förstasidan" : "";"  it the isset value thats the problem.

Comment: I hate this huge feeling of man love(based upon the fact that you are a man) I feel when getting help with simple stuff like this. But thank you! That worked perfect. Learned something very useful there!